# In Doctor Who "It Takes You Away" - why didn't anyone notice Hanne was blind?

Tags: doctor-who

The Doctor tells Ryan and Graham to go upstairs to check the rest of the cabin, but then Ryan and Graham find Hanne in the wardrobe hiding - the Doctor and Yaz run upstairs to find Hanne upstairs. They all say something and Graham says he has a sandwich... the next shot is downstairs in the kitchen and them talking. Then Hanne feels her way to the sink - the Doctor says something about are you blind to Hanne and everyone is then surprised/shocked.

Now here is the question, how did Hanne go downstairs to the kitchen/dining area and not give away that she was blind? Throughout the whole episode she is feeling her way through to get to somewhere she needs to go... did I miss something in the episode?

Comment: She's familiar with her own house, she knows where everything is, where to step, etc. Less need to feel around. That is not the case once she takes the portal into the anti-zone. More need to feel around

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sequence of events are as follows:

1. They find a child hidden in a closet. Shaking, terrified, perhaps crying.
2. They decide to go down to the kitchen. The child follows them.
3. She already knows the path/distance to the stairs, to the nearby walls. She moves slowly, holding/touching the wall - it's perfectly normal for them, considering the bad physiological state she is.
4. In the kitchen, nobody notices her blindness because she seems to avoid eye contact with everyone. Logical as they are a bunch of strangers in her house.
5. But... when she turns to put her plate to the sink, she tries to find her way by touch. Touching the sink to locate where to put her plate. All companions see her back, they are unable to monitor/observe what she's doing.
6. Except the Doctor, she has direct eye contact with her as she is standing next to her, she watches her movements and it is at that moment she asks:

   > Are you blind?

Comment: ok, seems logical... but in your point 3 - "She moves slowly, holding/touching the wall.." someone would've said "Hey, are you alright?" and then would've known something was wrong... especially, if everyone else is moving at normal speed down stairs. I'll accept your answer, but still seems weird that no one noticed.

Comment: @Pikachun.. (speculation only) short distance from bedroom in top floor to the kitchen, or not paying attention to your fellow humans but focusing in hearing/smelling external noises/smells, or not paying attention at all, or plot hote. Take your pick